# Broken email module on Heroku for Python 3.4

Tags: python, email, heroku, importerror

Whenever I execute a script on Heroku that imports the flask app module it throws the following error that email.Utils can't be found:

```
File "/app/mod/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
from flask import Flask
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from werkzeug.exceptions import abort
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/werkzeug/__init__.py", line 154, in <module>
    __import__('werkzeug.exceptions')
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/werkzeug/exceptions.py", line 71, in <module>
    from werkzeug.wrappers import Response
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/werkzeug/wrappers.py", line 26, in <module>
    from werkzeug.http import HTTP_STATUS_CODES, \
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/werkzeug/http.py", line 24, in <module>
    from email.Utils import parsedate_tz
ImportError: No module named 'email.Utils'
```

I installed a new python runtime on Heroku, with no change.

If I inspect the email module on Heroku I get:

```
>>> import email
>>> email.__file__
'/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/email/__init__.py'
>>> dir(email)
['__all__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', '__version__', 'message_from_binary_file', 'message_from_bytes', 'message_from_file', 'message_from_string']
```

**There's no Utils or utils. What is going on here? Thx**

Comment: In my local install of Python 3.4 it's `email.utils` not `Utils`

Comment: werkzeug/http.py tries both variants. `email.utils` and `email.Utils`, neither exists.